# Shape Error in Andrew NG Logistic Regression using Scipy.opt

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scipy

I've been trying to write Andrew NG's Logistic Regression Problem Using python and Scipy.opt for optimizing the function. However, I get a VALUE ERROR that says I have mismatching dimensions. I've tried to flatten() my theta array as scipy.opt doesn't seem to work very well with single column/row vector, however the problem still persists.

Kindly point me in the right direction as to what is causing the problem and how to avoid it.

Thanks a million!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize as opt

dataset = pd.read_csv("Students Exam Dataset.txt", names=["Exam 1", "Exam 2", "Admitted"])
print(dataset.head())

positive = dataset[dataset["Admitted"] == 1]
negative = dataset[dataset["Admitted"] == 0]

#Visualizing Dataset
plt.scatter(positive["Exam 1"], positive["Exam 2"], color="blue", marker="o", label="Admitted")
plt.scatter(negative["Exam 1"], negative["Exam 2"], color="red", marker="x", label="Not Admitted")
plt.xlabel("Exam 1 Score")
plt.ylabel("Exam 2 Score")
plt.title("Admission Graph")
plt.legend()
#plt.show()

#Preprocessing Data
dataset.insert(0, "x0", 1)
col = len(dataset.columns)
x = dataset.iloc[:,0:col-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:,col-1:col].values
b = np.zeros([1,col-1])
m = len(y)
print(f"X Shape: {x.shape}   Y Shape: {y.shape}   B Shape: {b.shape}")

#Defining Functions
def hypothesis(x, y, b):
    h = 1 / (1+np.exp(-x @ b.T))
    return h

def cost(x, y, b):
    first = (y.T @ np.log(hypothesis(x, y, b)))
    second = (1-y).T @ np.log(1 - hypothesis(x, y, b))
    j = (-1/m) * np.sum(first+second)
    return j

def gradient(x, y, b):
    grad_step = ((hypothesis(x, y, b) - y) @ x.T) / m
    return b

#Output
initial_cost = cost(x, y, b)
print(f"\nInitial Cost = {initial_cost}")
final_cost = opt.fmin_tnc(func=cost, x0=b.flatten() , fprime=gradient, args=(x,y))
print(f"Final Cost = {final_cost} \nTheta = {b}")
```

Dataset Used: ex2.txt

```
34.62365962451697,78.0246928153624,0
30.28671076822607,43.89499752400101,0
35.84740876993872,72.90219802708364,0
60.18259938620976,86.30855209546826,1
79.0327360507101,75.3443764369103,1
45.08327747668339,56.3163717815305,0
61.10666453684766,96.51142588489624,1
75.02474556738889,46.55401354116538,1
76.09878670226257,87.42056971926803,1
84.43281996120035,43.53339331072109,1
95.86155507093572,38.22527805795094,0
75.01365838958247,30.60326323428011,0
82.30705337399482,76.48196330235604,1
69.36458875970939,97.71869196188608,1
39.53833914367223,76.03681085115882,0
53.9710521485623,89.20735013750205,1
69.07014406283025,52.74046973016765,1
67.94685547711617,46.67857410673128,0
70.66150955499435,92.92713789364831,1
76.97878372747498,47.57596364975532,1
67.37202754570876,42.83843832029179,0
89.67677575072079,65.79936592745237,1
50.534788289883,48.85581152764205,0
34.21206097786789,44.20952859866288,0
77.9240914545704,68.9723599933059,1
62.27101367004632,69.95445795447587,1
80.1901807509566,44.82162893218353,1
93.114388797442,38.80067033713209,0
61.83020602312595,50.25610789244621,0
38.78580379679423,64.99568095539578,0
61.379289447425,72.80788731317097,1
85.40451939411645,57.05198397627122,1
52.10797973193984,63.12762376881715,0
52.04540476831827,69.43286012045222,1
40.23689373545111,71.16774802184875,0
54.63510555424817,52.21388588061123,0
33.91550010906887,98.86943574220611,0
64.17698887494485,80.90806058670817,1
74.78925295941542,41.57341522824434,0
34.1836400264419,75.2377203360134,0
83.90239366249155,56.30804621605327,1
51.54772026906181,46.85629026349976,0
94.44336776917852,65.56892160559052,1
82.36875375713919,40.61825515970618,0
51.04775177128865,45.82270145776001,0
62.22267576120188,52.06099194836679,0
77.19303492601364,70.45820000180959,1
97.77159928000232,86.7278223300282,1
62.07306379667647,96.76882412413983,1
91.56497449807442,88.69629254546599,1
79.94481794066932,74.16311935043758,1
99.2725269292572,60.99903099844988,1
90.54671411399852,43.39060180650027,1
34.52451385320009,60.39634245837173,0
50.2864961189907,49.80453881323059,0
49.58667721632031,59.80895099453265,0
97.64563396007767,68.86157272420604,1
32.57720016809309,95.59854761387875,0
74.24869136721598,69.82457122657193,1
71.79646205863379,78.45356224515052,1
75.3956114656803,85.75993667331619,1
35.28611281526193,47.02051394723416,0
56.25381749711624,39.26147251058019,0
30.05882244669796,49.59297386723685,0
44.66826172480893,66.45008614558913,0
66.56089447242954,41.09209807936973,0
40.45755098375164,97.53518548909936,1
49.07256321908844,51.88321182073966,0
80.27957401466998,92.11606081344084,1
66.74671856944039,60.99139402740988,1
32.72283304060323,43.30717306430063,0
64.0393204150601,78.03168802018232,1
72.34649422579923,96.22759296761404,1
60.45788573918959,73.09499809758037,1
58.84095621726802,75.85844831279042,1
99.82785779692128,72.36925193383885,1
47.26426910848174,88.47586499559782,1
50.45815980285988,75.80985952982456,1
60.45555629271532,42.50840943572217,0
82.22666157785568,42.71987853716458,0
88.9138964166533,69.80378889835472,1
94.83450672430196,45.69430680250754,1
67.31925746917527,66.58935317747915,1
57.23870631569862,59.51428198012956,1
80.36675600171273,90.96014789746954,1
68.46852178591112,85.59430710452014,1
42.0754545384731,78.84478600148043,0
75.47770200533905,90.42453899753964,1
78.63542434898018,96.64742716885644,1
52.34800398794107,60.76950525602592,0
94.09433112516793,77.15910509073893,1
90.44855097096364,87.50879176484702,1
55.48216114069585,35.57070347228866,0
74.49269241843041,84.84513684930135,1
89.84580670720979,45.35828361091658,1
83.48916274498238,48.38028579728175,1
42.2617008099817,87.10385094025457,1
99.31500880510394,68.77540947206617,1
55.34001756003703,64.9319380069486,1
74.77589300092767,89.52981289513276,1
```

Comment: This doesn't have to do anything with scikit-learn. Removed the tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay! So I figured out the answer myself after scouring through the depths of Github. The Value error has nothing to do with the shapes of your array. First I had to modify my Optimization function to:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
results = minimize(cost, b, args = (x,y),
                   method = 'CG', jac = compute_gradient, 
                   options = {"maxiter": 400, "disp" : True})
```

The code still didn't work because the arguments to my functions were in the order (X,y,theta). In order to get the function to work correctly I had to change the order of the arguments to (theta, X, y). It made me wonder if this order mattered. So I applied this change to my function and immediately the optimization worked!

In retrospect, I understand why theta must be the first argument that is passed into the cost and gradient functions. This is because the interface of the minimize function in scipy.optimize expects its x0 argument to be the initial guess, ie. the initialized parameter values.